# Install a C program to another machine without share code

Tags: c, unix, compilation

I need to install a C program UNIX to another UNIX machine, what can I do?

In case the other machine has different architecture how can I share my program in the best way?

Comment: If they use the same architecture just copy the compiled program to the target machine and run it

Comment: Yes of course I am referring to the generic case where this does not happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to share your program is compile it and share the binaries. There are a lot of open question you will have to solve (libraries dependencies, specific distribution configurations, ...). You must to precompile for every targeted hardware architecture (x86-64, ARM, ...) and for every specific SO (BSD, Linux, ... even Windows).

As an example, [Gimp](https://github.com/GNOME/gimp) is coded in **C/C++** and exists binaries for many hardware architectures and operating systems.

Comment: There is no other way?

Comment: Scripting and virtualization, but are not C/C++ related.